# Neo4j batch insert - version mismatch?

Tags: import, neo4j

I'm attempting to insert data into Neo4J using the Java APIs described here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert-examples.html .  I downloaded `neo4j-community-2.1.6-unix.tar.gz` and unpacked it, then created a `BatchInserters.inserter("/path/to/neo4j/data/graph.db")` and began the import process.

My Java project uses the following Maven dependency to get Neo4j:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-M01</version>
</dependency>
```

If I run the import and data already exists at `data/graph.db` (even by doing just a `bin/neo4j start; bin/neo4j stop`), then I get this error:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NotCurrentStoreVersionException:
  Was expecting store version [v0.A.4] but found [StringPropertyStore v0.A.3].
  Store cannot be upgraded automatically. 
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreVersionMismatchHandler$1.mismatch(StoreVersionMismatchHandler.java:38)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.verifyCorrectTypeDescriptorAndVersion(CommonAbstractStore.java:322)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkVersion(CommonAbstractStore.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(DynamicStringStore.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newDynamicStringStore(StoreFactory.java:254)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeTokenStore(StoreFactory.java:273)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeTokenStore(StoreFactory.java:260)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:257)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:51)
```

If I instead leave the `data/graph.db` directory uncreated and perform the import, the import seems to go as planned, but I can't start up the database afterward - here's what's in the log after an unsuccessful `bin/neo4j start`:

```
% cat data/log/console.log
2014-12-11 21:52:22.942+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
```

No actual recovery seems to be performed though, as far as I can tell.

If I need an older version of the importer codebase or something, where could I find that?

Comment: When you say that you leave the directory uncreated, import as planned, and then can't start up the database afterwards...what are you doing after the import?  Presumably the DB is already started.  Are you trying to start it again, or did you kill the server, or what's happening?

Comment: My understanding is that the import process doesn't connect to a started DB, it simply creates raw files at `data/graph.db/`.  So there's no DB running during or directly after the import.

Comment: Ken, that's incorrect (or largely so).  When you start the neo server, it attaches to that location BY DEFAULT (but configurable via files).  Depending on how you do the import, you may be running embedded, in which case the rules are different.   There must be a DB running during the import, otherwise the import can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it was as easy as changing my Maven dependency to `<version>2.1.6</version>`.  Duh.